# Delete post to MySQL using React.js and Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm having trouble deleting a post with React and MySQL. I'm not getting any errors or warnings but the posts aren't being deleted and when I console.log the affected rows it returns 0.

```
deleteNote = id => {
    // <-- declare id parameter
    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:5000/delete/${id}`) // <-- remove ;
      .then(() => {
        // Issue GET request after item deleted to get updated list
        // that excludes note of id
        this.getAllNotes()
      })
      .then(res => {
        const allNotes = res.data;
        this.setState({ allNotes });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };
```

```
<button
type="button"
className="btn-xs btn-info float-right"
onClick={() => this.props.deleteNote(note.ID)}>
<span>
<i className="fas fa-trash-alt" />
</span>{" "}
Delete
</button>
```

my delete method in express properly console logs the correct post id

```
app.delete("/delete/:id", (req, res) => {
  let { ID } = req.params.id;
  let sql = "DELETE FROM notes WHERE ID= ?";
  console.log("id: ", req.params.id);

  // delete a row with id = req.params.id
  connection.query(sql, [ID], (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) return console.error(error.message);

    console.log("Deleted Row(s):", results.affectedRows);
  });
});
```

Comment: When you use brace notation you must explicitly `return` things inside then() otherwise they will not be forwarded in the promise chain. In your code, this.getAllNotes() isn’t actually returned for the next then() to utilize its response.

Comment: Thanks I updated the code. I also added a return statement and it didn't work. I thinking the problem is on the server side

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I changed the way I used the parameters. Anybody know why passing ID as the second parameter wasn't working?

```
app.delete("/delete/:id", (req, res) => {
  let { ID } = req.params.id;
  let sql = `DELETE FROM notes WHERE ID = ${req.params.id}`;
  console.log("id: ", req.params.id);

  // delete a row with id = req.params.id
  connection.query(sql, (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) return console.error(error.message);
    res.status(200).send(results);
    console.log("Deleted Row(s):", results.affectedRows);
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to get `id` from `req.params`? It would be `let { id} = req.params`. It’s case sensitive when you use destructuring assignment. Not ID, but id and you need to target the object req.params not req.params.id

Answer (score 0):

You have to add at the end of ?.. it should be. ?, ID